# MySQL selecting MAX unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, max

I have a mysql table that shows the sellers table  that looks like the following:

```
advertiseid[pk] | customerid[fk] | productsid[fk] | quantites_advertised | price_advertised
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1               2                2                4.00                 2.00 
      2               4                3                5.00                 2.50
      3               3                2                1.00                 1.00
```

The first record means ..This means customer id 2 is selling choclates(product id 1), for 4KG's@ £2.00

I wanted to select each product ID so that the query displays the minimum of the different products: Hence, the table would be:

```
advertiseid[pk] | customerid[fk] | productsid[fk] | quantites_advertised | price_advertised
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          2               4                3                5.00                 2.50
          3               3                2                1.00                 1.00
```

The query outputs the min price for product 2 and 3 since product 3 is the only product with the cheapest price and product 2 the min between 4.00 and 1.00 is  1.00 hence, this is outputted. Say I have various different products how would I be able to achieve something like this? I have tried this query but it is incorrect.:

```
select c.Fname p.ProductName, s.ProductID, s.Quantity, s.Price 
FROM sellers s, products p, customer c
WHERE s.Price = (select MIN(Price) FROM sellers WHERE 
p.ID=s.ProductID AND c.ID=s.cid);
```

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filtering `inner join`:

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt
join    (
        select  productsid
        ,       min(price_advertised) as min_price_advertised
        from    YourTable
        group by
                productsid
        ) filter
on      filter.productsid = yt.productsid
        and filter.min_price_advertised = yt.price_advertised
```

Comment: Wow thanks man this works just like I wanted. Iv spent ages on this and couldn't get it to work. I'm going to now try and modify it so that it shows the cheapest price product as requested by the user. If I get stuck is it okay if I ask you?

Comment: If you've got a new question, ask a new question.  There are many knowledgeable users on StackOverflow who are happy to help!

Comment: No, I meant help for this perticular question you gave an answer to. But yes I understand thanks for your help once again:)

Comment: Hi, I am getting a problem when trying to match the "Requested product id" with the seller Product id.. This is what I am trying...
`select c.FName, sp.Description, sp.Quantity from customers c, sellerProducts sp, customerDemand d
join(
select ProductID, min(Price) min_Price from sellerProducts group by ProductID) filter on filter.ProductID = sp.ProductID AND filter.min_Price = sp.Price AND d.ProductID=sp.ProductID AND c.ID=sp.cid`

This seems to be giving me an error. What might I be doing wrong mate?

Comment: Use joins instead of listing multiple tables after the where clause.  See [bad habits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)